# C implementation of MD5 gives wrong hash

Tags: c, hash, md5

Recently, I did my own C implementation of the md5 algorithm. I know that open-source libraries exist, but I wanted to do so for practice. 
My implementation returns the right digest on the empty string "", however it does not return the right digest for "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog". Since it works with the empty string, I kind of assume that it either has to do with padding or the appending of the length to the end of the block.

Here my code:

```
/*
 * md5.c
 *
 *  Created on: Mar 25, 2020
 */

#include "checksum_algorithms.h"
#include "math.h"
#include "stdlib.h"

/**************************************************************************
 * Local variables
 *************************************************************************/

uint32_t K[] =
    {0xd76aa478, 0xe8c7b756, 0x242070db, 0xc1bdceee,
    0xf57c0faf, 0x4787c62a, 0xa8304613, 0xfd469501,
    0x698098d8, 0x8b44f7af, 0xffff5bb1, 0x895cd7be,
    0x6b901122, 0xfd987193, 0xa679438e, 0x49b40821,
    0xf61e2562, 0xc040b340, 0x265e5a51, 0xe9b6c7aa,
    0xd62f105d, 0x02441453, 0xd8a1e681, 0xe7d3fbc8,
    0x21e1cde6, 0xc33707d6, 0xf4d50d87, 0x455a14ed,
    0xa9e3e905, 0xfcefa3f8, 0x676f02d9, 0x8d2a4c8a,
    0xfffa3942, 0x8771f681, 0x6d9d6122, 0xfde5380c,
    0xa4beea44, 0x4bdecfa9, 0xf6bb4b60, 0xbebfbc70,
    0x289b7ec6, 0xeaa127fa, 0xd4ef3085, 0x04881d05,
    0xd9d4d039, 0xe6db99e5, 0x1fa27cf8, 0xc4ac5665,
    0xf4292244, 0x432aff97, 0xab9423a7, 0xfc93a039,
    0x655b59c3, 0x8f0ccc92, 0xffeff47d, 0x85845dd1,
    0x6fa87e4f, 0xfe2ce6e0, 0xa3014314, 0x4e0811a1,
    0xf7537e82, 0xbd3af235, 0x2ad7d2bb, 0xeb86d391};

uint32_t s[] =
    { 7, 12, 17, 22, 7, 12, 17, 22, 7, 12, 17, 22, 7, 12, 17, 22,
      5, 9, 14, 20, 5, 9, 14, 20, 5, 9, 14, 20, 5, 9, 14, 20,
      4, 11, 16, 23, 4, 11, 16, 23, 4, 11, 16, 23, 4, 11, 16, 23,
      6, 10, 15, 21, 6, 10, 15, 21, 6, 10, 15, 21, 6, 10, 15, 21};

uint32_t a0 = 0x67452301;
uint32_t b0 = 0xEFCDAB89;
uint32_t c0 = 0x98BADCFE;
uint32_t d0 = 0x10325476;

/**************************************************************************
 * Local functions
 *************************************************************************/

static uint32_t SWAPWORD32(uint32_t x)
{
    return
    (((x >> 24) & 0xff) |
    ((x << 8) & 0xff0000) |
    ((x >> 8) & 0xff00) |
    ((x << 24) & 0xff000000));
}

static uint32_t leftrotate(uint32_t x, uint16_t N)
{
    return ((x << N) | ((x & 0xFFFFFFFF) >> (32-N)));
}

static uint32_t f(uint32_t x, uint32_t y, uint32_t z)
{
    return ((x & y) | (~x & z));
}

static uint32_t g(uint32_t x, uint32_t y, uint32_t z)
{
    return ((x & z) | (y & ~z));
}

static uint32_t h(uint32_t x, uint32_t y, uint32_t z)
{
    return (x ^ y ^ z);
}

static uint32_t i(uint32_t x, uint32_t y, uint32_t z)
{
    return (y ^ (x | ~z));
}

static void length_padding(uint8_t* pWords, uint64_t bitSize, uint64_t* padSize)
{
    uint64_t fullBytes = bitSize >> 3;
    /* Fill the remaining byte with zeros */
    uint64_t remaining_bytes = (512 - bitSize - 64)%512 >> 3;;
    memset(pWords + fullBytes, 0, remaining_bytes);
    *(pWords + fullBytes) = (1 << 7);
    /* Add the length */
    memcpy(pWords + fullBytes + remaining_bytes, &bitSize, sizeof(bitSize));
    *padSize = (fullBytes + remaining_bytes + 8) << 3;
}

/**************************************************************************
 * Global functions
 *************************************************************************/

void calculate_md5(void* pData, uint64_t bitSize, uint32_t* digest)
{
    int k, j;
    uint32_t G, F, temp;
    uint32_t* pBuf = (uint32_t*)pData;
    uint64_t padSize = 0;

    uint32_t A, B, C, D;
    length_padding((uint8_t*)pBuf, bitSize, &padSize);

    for (k = 0; k < padSize/512; k++)
    {
        A = a0;
        B = b0;
        C = c0;
        D = d0;
        for (j = 0; j < 64; j++)
        {
            if (j < 16)
            {
                F = f(B, C, D);
                G = j;
            }
            else if (j < 32)
            {
                F = g(B, C, D);
                G = (5*j + 1)%16;
            }
            else if (j < 48)
            {
                F = h(B, C, D);
                G = (3*j + 5)%16;
            }
            else if (j < 64)
            {
                F = i(B, C, D);
                G = (7*j)%16;
            }
            temp = D;
            D = C;
            C = B;
            B += leftrotate(A + F + K[j] + (uint32_t)(*(pBuf + G + k*MD5_BUF_LEN/4)), s[j]);
            A = temp;
        }
        a0 += A;
        b0 += B;
        c0 += C;
        d0 += D;
    }

    uint32_t hash[4] = {SWAPWORD32(a0), SWAPWORD32(b0), SWAPWORD32(c0), SWAPWORD32(d0)};
    memcpy(digest, hash, sizeof(hash));

}
```

The header file "checksum_algorithms.h" just contains a few function prototypes, and definitions. MD5_BUF_LEN is defined as 64. 
I then call the function in main() as follows:

```
String md5_test = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
uint32_t digest[4] = {0, 0, 0, 0};
calculate_md5(&md5_test, strlen(md5_test)*8, digest);
```

Does anybody see where the problem origins from? 
I know that this is a very basic example, but I am grateful for any tips, also if you have any inputs on coding style. And as a side note: I am running this example on a 32-bit processor with byte order little endian.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: `String md5_test` - are you using `cs50`? What is `String`? `memset(pWords + fullBytes, 0, remaining_bytes);` - Assuming `typedef char *String;` then: no, you can't do that. There is no memory there. A string literal is immutable. You can't write to it. And you can't write behind it. `memcpy(pWords + fullBytes + remaining_bytes, &bitSize, sizeof(bitSize));` no, you can't write to `pWords`. You have to allocate new memory for the new string.

Comment: Yes, but I pass the pointer uint32_t* pBuf. It just points to the address of the String/char*. And if I increment the address by the length of the string, I should point to just the memory after the string (it is perhaps quite unsafe to do so without using malloc first!). But actually, you gave me the hint why it didn't work:) of course I have to pass md5_test instead of &md5_test to the function :) So thank you :)

Comment: No. String literals are immutable. Can't be modified. End of story. `I should point to just the memory after the string (it is perhaps quite unsafe to do so without using malloc first!).` - no, there is no such thing as "unsafe". It is undefined behavior. It will not work. It will fail. It may happen to work, which is a perfectly valid manifestation of undefined behavior. `I have to pass md5_test instead of &md5_test to the function` Right, good catch.

Comment: Agreed. Thank you for your input.